# Making dependant fields in my form

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, forms, symfony1

I am using the framework Symfony in my project.
I want to add 2 dependant fields in my form:

- The user must select a rubric from the first list
- and the second list generates automatically the items of this rubric.

I am not an experiment in Javascript and Ajax.

Answer (score 3):

For Symfony2 you can use ShtumiUsefulBundle https://github.com/shtumi/ShtumiUsefulBundle.
It provides dependent filtered entity form types.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this plugin:
[sfDependentSelectPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfDependentSelectPlugin)

It solved my problem.